# Problems with "normal" blending of two images with alpha

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I'm trying to do some blending of images in Java. After succcesfully doing multiply and screen blending, "normal" blending is causing me headaches.

I found on Wikipedia that the formula for blending two pixels with alpha is:
[image]
*Co being resulting color, Ca color of top image, Cb color of bottom image and Aa -> alpha of top, Ab -> alpha of bottom.*

I've tried to translate this to Java, and now have:

*(t_X == Components from top image, b_X == Components from bottom image)*

```
float t_a = (topPixels[i] >> 24) & 0xff, t_r = (topPixels[i] >> 16) & 0xff, t_g = (topPixels[i] >> 8) & 0xff, t_b = topPixels[i] & 0xff;
float b_a = (bottomPixels[i] >> 24) & 0xff, b_r = (bottomPixels[i] >> 16) & 0xff, b_g = (bottomPixels[i] >> 8) & 0xff, b_b = bottomPixels[i] & 0xff;

destPixels[i] = 
    (255 << 24 |
    (int)((t_r * t_a) + ((b_r * b_a) * (((255 - t_a) / 255)))) << 16 |  
    (int)((t_g * t_a) + ((b_g * b_a) * (((255 - t_a) / 255)))) << 8 |   
    (int)((t_b * t_a) + ((b_b * b_a) * (((255 - t_a) / 255)))) << 0                     
);
```

But this seems to be wrong as the resulting image comes out wrong.

Any ideas what I'm missing, or is my lack of mathematical skill getting the best of me again when translating the formula to code?

Comment: t_r, t_a are floats, ints (0-255), or...? The maths looks alright, but all the casts look weird (`(255 - t_a) / 255` isn't that just zero for ints?) and I miss some `& 0xff`? No expert, but maybe you could try 3 ints, check them, then combine them in dest.

Comment: You could let the JRE do the work for you. For just blending one image on top of the other, a simple Graphics.drawImage() could do the trick - as long as the images are of a kind that supports alpha (e.g. BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB). Also take a look at Graphics2D.setComposite() and AlphaComposite.getInstance(), most of the stuff is already there, and its potentially hardware accelerated.

Comment: @Durandal: My target platform doesn't provide java.awt. (I'll edit the tags, as this wasn't evident from the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change a lot of this.

t_r, t_a etc must all be floats from 0 to 1. Do all your calculations in floating point, then multiply by 255 and then cast to int.

Comment: Did that, no help. Image still comes out wrong. Code here: http://pastebin.com/9YVU53nU

Comment: Ah, I was missing one division by 255 in the beginning, now it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If t_a is not a floating point value, then calculations such as (255 - t_a) / 255 are done as integers too. You need to cast one of your inputs to a float beforehand, e.g ((255 - t_a) / 255f).